# solutions and graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

For this graph, we are graphing all of the time this person is walking or resting. If he takes a break to rest for 10 mins, the graph will not stop. It should continue. Time will continue, but he will not be moving so the total distance that he has traveled will not change.
For example, if he walked 500 feet in the first 10 minutes of this walk and then stopped to rest. This ordered pair would be (10,500). Now, if he rest 10 mins. At 11 minutes the point would be (11,500) .

What points would represent 12 minutes and 16 minutes? What would the graph be doing at this time?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: If he's going to rest for $10$ minutes starting at $t=10$, then has he started moving again at $t=12$? At $t=16$?